# Rails passing information from a view to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that includes Requests and Workorders tables.

I have a New Workorder button on the Request show page.  I need to pass information from the Request to the Workorder - for instance the Request.id.

I'm currently using flash to do this.  Here is the button on the Request show page:

```
<%= link_to 'New Work Order', new_workorder_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick =>  (flash[:request_id] = @request.id  %>
```

In the new Workorder form, I have:

```
  <% if flash[:request_id] != nil %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :request_id, :value => flash[:request_id] %>
```

This works.  But, not always.  And I haven't been able to figure out why it fails sometimes.

Is there a better way to pass this data?

Thanks for the help!!

UDPDATE1

Sometimes I need to bring forward quite a few data fields.  For example:

```
       <%= link_to 'Follow-up Work Order', new_workorder_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => ( flash[:workorder_id] = @workorder.id, flash[:client_id] = @workorder.client_id, flash[:contact_id] = @workorder.contact_id, flash[:location_id] = @workorder.location_id, flash[:type_id] = @workorder.type_id, flash[:woasset_id] = @workorder.woasset_id) %>
```

Comment: this can't work: js is client side, flash setting is server side

Comment: It actually does work.  But, every once in a while it doesn't.  I'm not sure what the end-user is doing when it fails.  I'm trying to determine the actions taken when it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try passing the parameter to the path of the link and then pass it to the form via your controller's action:

Link:

```
<%= link_to 'New Work Order', new_workorder_path(request_id: @request.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Controller

```
def new
  @request_id = params[:request_id]
  ...
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :request_id, value: @request_id %>
```

Comment: Would param be any better than flash?  Aren't they similar?  I use flash, because it gets returned to nil after the next page.

Comment: @Reddirt This solutions seems to be the cleanest, even though you don't have to use a class viariable `@request_id`, you can use `params[:request_id]` directly in the view.

Comment: MrYoshiji - where would the `params[:request_id]` go in the view?  When would it be reset to nil?  If it doen't become nil, then I'll have problems.

Comment: A problem is that even though I'm setting flash or param in the onclick, it's getting set when the page loads - even if the user doesn't click on the button.

Comment: Does the `def new` in the above answer go in the workorder controller?

Comment: OK - I got one parameter working - thanks!!!  But how do I add a second parameter?  Something like this `<%= link_to 'New Work Order', new_workorder_path(request_id: @request.id, client_id: @client_id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>`