# Rails redirect to previous page (back) after delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to include a redirect in a link_to?  I want to just refresh the current page after a delete.  But, you can delete the same record from multiple views in the app.

This is the link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', expense, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
```

If not, does it make sense to save the current_url in flash[:fromurl] then put that in the Controller destroy section like this:

```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to flash[:fromurl] }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered making the link remote so that you can handle the refreshing of a particular div with js and that way you won't have to reload the whole page?

Comment: Maybe `redirect_to :back`?

Comment: That sounds great - but, I have no idea to to start doing it.  Any where you could point me for an explanation?

Comment: @Reddirt Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052650/link-to-and-remote-true-jquery-how-help

Comment: MrYoshi - that works and is a whole lot simpler than using flash - thanks!!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `redirect_to :back` :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

It uses the header "HTTP_REFERER" from the request:

```
redirect_to :back
# is a shorthand for:
redirect_to request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Comment: MrYoshiji,  I was wondering if you would be willing to look at this questions for me?  I would really appreciate it.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279090/rails-passing-information-from-a-view-to-a-form

Comment: MrYoshiji - the redirect_to :back works if you delete from any page except the show page.  Because, the back tries to take you back to show a record you just deleted.  I've posted a new question.

Comment: @Reddirt did you every find out how to not get `:back` to try and send you to the record that was just removed?

Comment: @Gcap You should not `redirect_to :back` after a successfull destroy action, but do a `redirect_to action: :index` instead (for example)

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 5 ([Official Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)) you can use the updated:
 `redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)`

Using this redirects the user to the referring page (previous page, the same as `redirect_to :back`). If this isn't possible, it then redirects to a fallback location specified in the controller.

An example of a method in your controller (this redirects the user to the **root path** as a fallback location):

```
def some_method
    #Your Code Here
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end
```

An example of a method for deleting an `expense` and redirecting back, with a fallback to the `root_path`:

```
def destroy
    @expense.destroy
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
end
```

Below are some other examples of the `fallback_location`'s that can be used to redirect the browser back to a specific page, if the referring page cannot be redirected to:

```
redirect_back fallback_location: "http://www.google.com"      #Redirects to Google (or any website you specify)
redirect_back fallback_location:  "/images/screenshot.jpg"    #Redirects to a local image
redirect_back fallback_location:  posts_path                  #Redirects to the 'posts' path
redirect_back fallback_location:  new_user_path               #Redirects to the new user path
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one.

```
render :nothing => true
```